# Pygame - How to Fill an object gradually from bottom to top?

Tags: python, events, pygame

I'm currently working on a game based around working a restaurant, and one of the aspects im working on is filling a cup up with water, i'm choosing not to do water simulations as i'm no expert ahah but my idea of filling a cup up using rectangles one a top another when the mouse button is held is not working. Here's the section of code im trying to fix, any and all feedback is appreciated : ).

```
while True:
   e = pygame.event.wait()
   if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
       DrawWater = True       
   if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           print("Lol")
           WaterLine = False
   
   if DrawWater:
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 255], [300, WaterLine, 400, 1])
       WaterLine -= 1
   pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.event.wait()` wait for a single event from the queue and halts the application loop. Implement an event loop and use [`pygame.event.get`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get):

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick).

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
   clock.tick(60)
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           DrawWater = True       
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
           print("Lol")
           WaterLine = False
   
   if DrawWater:
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 255], [300, WaterLine, 400, 1])
       WaterLine -= 1
   pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed):

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 400))

WaterLine = 300

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
   clock.tick(60)
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
   
   if any(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()):
       pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 0, 255], [100, WaterLine, 100, 1])
       WaterLine -= 1
   pygame.display.flip()
```

---

The `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs once when you click the mouse button and the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event occurs once when the mouse button is released.
[`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons. The state of a button is `True` as long as a button is held down.

Comment: Your A lifesaver haha, I'm only starting out and keep forgetting the clock, got it all working now! cheers : )